# Accessing the Quick Panel in a Sublime Text 2 Plugin

Tags: python, sublimetext2

I'm in the process of learning how to create Sublime Text 2 plugins.  One of the things that I would like to do is take any highlighted text, check if a website will return a 200 at that address, and then place some information into the quick panel (and yes, I know that I should be doing the url lookup in a thread so that it doesn't block the main UI).  Currently I have:

```
import sublime
import sublime_plugin
import urllib2

class CheckUrlPanel(sublime_plugin.WindowCommand):

def quick_panel(self, messages, flags):
    self.window.show_quick_panel(messages, None, flags)

class CheckUrlsCommand(sublime_plugin.TextCommand):

def run(self, edit):
    urls = []
    selections = self.view.sel()
    for selection in selections:
        urls.append(self.view.substr(selection))

    messages = self.validate_urls(urls)
    panel = CheckUrlPanel()
    panel.quick_panel(messages, sublime.MONOSPACE_FONT)

def validate_urls(self, urls):
    messages = []
    for url in urls:
        try:
            request = urllib2.Request(url, headers={ "User-Agent" : "Sublime URL Checker" }) 
            response = urllib2.urlopen(request, timeout=3)
            message = '"%s" is a valid URL.' % url
        except Exception as (e):
            message = '"%s" is an invalid URL.' % url

        messages.append(message)

    return messages
```

The error I get is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "./sublime_plugin.py", line 362, in run_
File "./CheckUrls.py", line 19, in run
  panel = CheckUrlPanel()
  TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)
```

The problem is that I don't know how to initialize the WindowCommand class correctly, and I can't seem to find any documentation on it.  Any help or hints here would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You don't need to create another instance of `WindowCommand` to accomplish this. Btw, you usually write commands but don't create their instances in your plugins. They are instantiated and invoked via key bindings or `run_command` method of View/Window/sublime.

You can get the current active window inside your `check_urls` command handler and display a quick panel.

```
window = sublime.active_window()
window.show_quick_panel(messages, None, sublime.MONOSPACE_FONT)
```

Here is a full source:

```
import sublime
import sublime_plugin
import urllib
from urllib.request import urlopen

class CheckUrlsCommand(sublime_plugin.TextCommand):

   def run(self, edit):
      urls = []
      selections = self.view.sel()
      for selection in selections:
         urls.append(self.view.substr(selection))

      messages = self.validate_urls(urls)
      window = sublime.active_window()
      window.show_quick_panel(messages, None, sublime.MONOSPACE_FONT)

   def validate_urls(self, urls):
      messages = []
      for url in urls:
         try:                
            response = urlopen(request, timeout=3)
            message = '"%s" is a valid URL.' % url
         except Exception as e:
            message = '"%s" is an invalid URL.' % url

         messages.append(message)

      return messages
```

Comment: You are correct.  I figured this out about 20 minutes after I posted the bounty, but I appreciate your thorough answer regardless.  Thank you! (I'll award the bounty as soon as SO lets me)